# How install Redis extension on PHP?

Tags: php, redis

There are many articles about installing Redis ex on PHP

But I cannot fix my problem

I downloaded Redis ex from https://pecl.php.net/package/redis and placed it in the PHP folder

But there is no any Redis ext in wamp menu

However, I use Predis but I need to Redis ext

My the PHP version is 7.4

Comment: You are on Windows?

You will need to install Ubuntu through Windows WSL. Then you can install Redis inside the WSL.

Comment: @JamesShisiah What is WSL? Yes, I'm on Windows

Comment: @JamesShisiah That's not true. PHP, and its extensions, can run natively on Windows, and the OP already references "WAMP", which is the name of an installer for that.

Comment: @IMSoP yes, of course. But the issue is Redis.

Comment: @JamesShisiah No, the issue is a PHP extension for _talking to_ Redis.

Answer (score 0):

I had an error on Mac

```php
Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires PHP extension ext-redis * but it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's redis extension.

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/php8.1.13.ini
```

The solution was to install redis extension

```php
mkdir redis && cd redis
curl -O http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz
tar xzvf redis-stable.tar.gz
cd redis-stable
make
make test
sudo make install
```